# How to do this regex command?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

This would best be explained with examples.

Here is a line before I do anything:
**Monohydrogen_Phosphate HPO%4^2-**

Here is what I've done so far: **Monohydrogen Phosphate | HPO%4^2-**

Here is what it should be when finished: **Monohydrogen Phosphate | HPO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>**

The `%` will put the first number (if any) and + or - signs (if any) in a `<sub>` tag, and the `^` will put the first number and +/- in a `<sup>` tag.

I am using Javascript's RegEx replace, but I don't mind switching to PHP.

Comment: but can't the numbers be more than 1 digit? if there are chemical formulas, I am sure they can

Comment: @haynar - My code supports multi-digit numbers.

Comment: @Derek yes, I know :) I am just asking to improve my answer

Comment: @haynar yes, it would make sense. Although all of the current entries right only have single digits, there may be multi-digits entries in the future.

Comment: then the right answer is Derek's answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use

```
str.replace(/([^\|])\s+([a-z]+)(%(\d+[+-]?))?(\^(\d+[+-]?))?/gi,'$1 | $2<sub>$4</sub><sup>$6</sup>');
```

Here's an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var str = 'Monohydrogen_Phosphate HPO%4^2-';
    var str1 = str.replace(/([^\|])\s+([a-z]+)(%(\d+[+-]?))?(\^(\d+[+-]?))?/gi,'$1 | $2<sub>$4</sub><sup>$6</sup>');
    console.log('str:\t' + str + '\nstr1:\t' + str1);

</script>
```

which will output:

> **str:**	Monohydrogen_Phosphate HPO%4^2-
>   **str1:**	Monohydrogen_Phosphate | HPO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>
>
> *which, in HTML will be parsed like…*
>
> **Monohydrogen_Phosphate | HPO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>**

---

### EDIT:

I was thinking about compound(?) elements such as **Li<sub>2</sub>CO<sub>3</sub>** so I came up with a longer but better solution.

```
function formatStr(str) {

    return str.replace(/([a-z]+)(%(\d+[+-]?))?(\^(\d+[+-]?))?/gi,function() {
    // this part allows stuck elements to be parsed right
    // such as Li%2CO%3 or H%2SO%4
        if (!arguments[3] && !arguments[5]) return arguments[0];
        var _str = arguments[1];
        _str += arguments[3] ? '<sub>' + arguments[3] + '</sub>' : '';
        _str += arguments[5] ? '<sup>' + arguments[5] + '</sup>' : '';
        return _str;
    }).replace(/(.+)\s+([a-zA-Z]+<su[bp]>.+<\/su[bp]>)$/,'$1 | $2');
    // and this part adds ' | ' to the beginning of the changed element
    // if there's any content before it. otherwise it's left as is
}
```

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET added an example in my post.

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET Nevermind the empty tags, if any. They won't occupy physical space anyway unless you format those (sub/sup) elements via CSS.

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET I should have guessed such a short solution lacked something. And that's exactly why I added an alternative. You might wanna use that instead.

Answer (score 3):

```
var txt = "HPO%4^2-";
txt = txt.replace(/%(\d*[+-]?)/, "<sub>$1</sub>");
txt = txt.replace(/\^(\d*[+-]?)/, "<sup>$1</sup>");

txt     //HPO<sub>4</sub><sup>2-</sup>
```

Here you go.

For more information, see MDN [`replace` <sup><sub>- Example: Switching words in a string</sub></sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Example%3a_Switching_words_in_a_string).

Answer (score 2):

Example which allows digits and signs:

```
var str = "HPO%4^2-";
var html = str
    .replace(/%([\d\-+]+)/g, "<sub>$1</sub>")
    .replace(/\^([\d+\-]+)/g, "<sup>$1</sup>");
```

Note that the `/g` modifier will be needed if you wish to allow multiple replacements.

Answer (score 1):

Here is much better example:

```
var text = "Monohydrogen Phosphate | HPO%4^2-";
text = text.replace(/%(\d+[+-]?)/, "<sub>$1</sub>");
text = text.replace(/\^(\d+[+-]?)/, "<sup>$1</sup>");
```

Comment: Thank you to you and mogelbrod as well. Just another quick question: I noticed that you escaped '%' and Derek didn't. What is the recommendation on escaping/not escaping %?

Comment: I was note sure if the % sign could be considered as some special character or not, that's why I've escaped it

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET: % is not a magic character ([more info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html)) so there's no reason to escape it :)